# Vertical Navagation siblings not closing when another is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery

My vertical nav works except for that when I press on the sibling drop down the previous opened drop down does not collapse. I was wondering if you could help me with this.

Here is my javascript code and if you want to look at it in full here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/CLNBn/2/

```
$('.vertical-nav ul li:has("div")').find('div').hide();

$('.vertical-nav li:has("div")').find('span:first').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('li').find('span:first').toggleClass("closed opened");
    if ($(this).parent('li').find('span:first').attr('class') == 'closed') {
        $(this).parent('li').find('span:first').text('+');
    } else {
        $(this).parent('li').find('span:first').text('-');
    }
    $(this).parent('li').find('div:first').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: I have the feeling that `this` already refers to the `span:first` you are constantly searching for.

Comment: Hmm but it does drop down and toggle already just the siblings don't toggle the already opened slide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already gave your elements reasonable classes, this task is quite easy. What you want is to find all `span` elements with class `opened` that are children of the siblings of the current `li` element, and trigger their `click` event handler.

This can be done with:

```
$(this).closest('li').siblings().children('span.opened').click();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/CLNBn/5/)

I also took the liberty to simplify your code to:

```
$('.vertical-nav li:has("div")').find('span:first').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("closed opened");
    if ($this.hasClass('closed')) {
        $this.text('+');
    } else {
        $this.text('-');
        $this.closest('li').siblings().children('span.opened').click();
    }
    $this.closest('li').find('div').first().slideToggle();
});​
```

As I said in my comment, `this` already refers to the `span` element, there is no need to traverse up the DOM tree and search for it again.

Comment: Oh man I feel so dumb lol! Thank you so much! That worked PERFECTLY!